# Magento 2: User login sometimes requires to login twice on multi store setup

Tags: magento2, multistore, login, store-switcher

I am trying to setup a multi store with shared cart. However, the user login sometimes does not work.

The `Store Switcher` works fine, but the frontend `User Login` on 2nd and 3rd `Store` requires me to click the `Sign In` button twice to login.

I have setup multi stores with these setups:

## Multi Domain (Virtual Hosts)

I am using one `Website`. The site will have three `Stores`. The domain names will share one common base domain. The additional stores will use **subdomains**.

I created **magento2.com** as the default base domain.

I created **store2.magento2.com** as the 2nd store.

I created **store3.magento2.com** as the 3rd store.

> [image]

## Root Categories and Test Products

I created **Store2 Root Category** and **Store3 Root Category**. I also created sub categories under each Root Category.

> [image]

I added one test product to each sub category.

> [image]

## Stores and Views

I did NOT change anything on **Main Website Store** and **Default Store View**.

I created **Store2** and **Store View 2** for 2nd store.

I created **Store3** and **Store View 3** for 3rd store.

> [image]

For **Store2**, I set **Store2** as `Name` and selected **Store2 Root Category** as `Root Category`.

> [image]

For **Store View 2**, I selected **Store2** as `Store`, used **Store View 2** as `Name`, and entered **store2** as `Store Code`.

> [image]

For 3rd `Store`, I set **Store3** as `Name` and selected **Store3 Root Category** as `Root Category`.

> [image]

For **Store View 3**, I selected **Store3** as `Store`, used **Store View 3** as `Name`, and entered **store3** as `Store Code`.

> [image]

## URL and Cookie setting

The `Configuration` screen now shows 5 choices under `Store View` drop-down:

1. `Default Config`
2. `Main Website`
3. `Default Store View`
4. **Store View 2**
5. **Store View 3**

> [image]

I changed URL and Cookie settings for  `Default Store View`, **Store View 2**, and **Store View 3**.

I did NOT change URL or Cookie settings for `Default Config` and `Main Website`.

For `Default Store View`, I changed `Cookie Path`.

> [image]

For **Store View 2**, I changed `Base URL` and `Cookie Path`.

> [image]
>
> [image]

For **Store View 3**, I changed `Base URL` and `Cookie Path`.

> [image]
>
> [image]

## Account Sharing

To share user accounts and shopping cart among multiple stores, I changed `Share Customer Accounts` from "Per Website" to **Global** under `Default Config`.

> [image]

## .htaccess change

I added these lines at the top of `.htaccess` file at the project root directory.

```
#Multi store setting
SetEnvIf Host magento2.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=default
SetEnvIf Host magento2.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store
SetEnvIf Host ^magento2.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=default
SetEnvIf Host ^magento2.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store

SetEnvIf Host store2.magento2.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=store2
SetEnvIf Host store2.magento2.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store
SetEnvIf Host ^store2.magento2.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=store2
SetEnvIf Host ^store2.magento2.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store

SetEnvIf Host store3.magento2.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=store3
SetEnvIf Host store3.magento2.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store
SetEnvIf Host ^store3.magento2.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=store3
SetEnvIf Host ^store3.magento2.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store
```

## index.php change

Using the `Store Switcher`, sometimes required to click twice to switch from store2/3 to the default. To fix this, I had to reset the value for `$_COOKIE['store']` at the index.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * Application entry point
 *
 * Example - run a particular store or website:
 * --------------------------------------------
 * require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
 * $params = $_SERVER;
 * $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'website2';
 * $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
 * $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
 * \/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app *\/
 * $app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');
 * $bootstrap->run($app);
 * --------------------------------------------
 *
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

try {
    require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo <<<HTML
<div style="font:12px/1.35em arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">
    <div style="margin:0 0 25px 0; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;">
        <h3 style="margin:0;font-size:1.7em;font-weight:normal;text-transform:none;text-align:left;color:#2f2f2f;">
        Autoload error</h3>
    </div>
    <p>{$e->getMessage()}</p>
</div>
HTML;
    exit(1);
}

// Fix store switcher bug on switching to the default store
if ( isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) == 'store' && isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ) {
    if ( !empty($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ) {
        $_COOKIE['store'] = $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'];
    }
}

$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

## User login sometimes requires to click twice

With the above setup, the `Store Switcher` is working fine. The shopping `Cart` is shared among all 3 Stores for both logged-in and not-logged-in users.

> [image]

However, on **Store2** and **Store3**, the frontend `user login` sometimes redirects back to the same login page. If I press the `Sign In` button on the redirected login page (2nd time to click this button), it let's me login.

Is there a way to fix this problem?

## Update: disabling `Cache`

I disabled the caching from command line:

```
php bin/magento cache:disable
```

With disabled cache, the `user login` on **Store2** and **Store3** became much more stable. It still redirected back to the login page 1 out of 10 attempts, but this change made the login to work better.

**However, the entire site became slow!!!**

Is there a way to properly configure the cache to make the `user login` to perform correctly on a multi `Store` setup?

Comment: Hi Did you able to fix the issue?? I'm also facing same issue on my site. Login details are not shared among stores under single website. Can you please share your solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We managed to make the store switcher and login a bit more stable with new configuration.

## Add Store Code to Urls

The biggest change was setting `Add Store Code to Urls` to "Yes".

Stores =>
Configuration in Settings section =>
select `Default Config` =>
Web in GENERAL section =>
Url Options =>
  change the `Add Store Code to Urls` to "Yes"

> [image]

## Remove Cookie Domain

Then, we removed `Cookie Domain` value from **Store2** and **Store3** from the Configuration page.

Stores =>
Configuration in Settings section =>
select **Store2** or **Store3** =>
Web in GENERAL section =>
Default Cookie Settings =>
  remove the value from `Cookie Domain` and leave it blank

> [image]

## Remove custom codes from `.htaccess` and `index.php`

Then, we removed custom code lines form `.htaccess` and `index.php`.

With the new configuration, the customization on these files were no longer needed. This is great, cleaner code.

After these changes, the store switcher, shared shopping cart, and user login became much more stable. Make sure you clear the cache after you make these changes.

#### Magento2 core upgrade and its effect on `.htaccess` and `index.php`

Before making config and file changes, we upgraded the Magento2 core from 2.1.0 to 2.1.3 using `composer`. (Reference: [Update Magento 2.1.2 for 2.1.3](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/150501/update-magento-2-1-2-for-2-1-3) )

We are not sure this will be a required part for this multi store configuration, but we performed it hoping the site will be more stable with latest updates from 2.1.3

We had 3 files modified which which were part of core and module files (these files are ignored by our Git version control):

1. .htaccess
2. index.php
3. dev/tools/grunt/configs/themes.js (Grunt config file to compile our custom theme css)

When we upgraded Magento2, these files are reset to initial state of 2.1.3. We did NOT have to manually clean up our `.htaccess` and `index.php` files. The file contents were automatically reset by the upgrade. This was a positive side effect.

But there was also a bad side effect. Our custom code in the Grunt config file was reset and erased by the core upgrade. We had to manually restore our custom code lines on this file.

I recommend to take file and DB backups before doing this core upgrade and config/file changes.

---

## Minifying Javascript might help

Minifying JS made the entire site more stable on our site.

Stores =>
Configuration in Settings section =>
select `Default Config` =>
Developer in ADVANCED section =>
JavaScript Settings =>
  set `Merge JavaScript Files` to "Yes" =>
  set `Enable JavaScript Bundling` to "Yes" =>
  set `Minify JavaScript Files` to "Yes" =>
then, clear cache

> [image]