# Update Magento 2.1.2 for 2.1.3

Tags: magento-2.1, upgrade

Could someone explain me a step by step to upgrade using ssh?

I have update seup wizard in admin panel but I got these errors!

[image]

Comment: I am having a problem upgrading from 2.1.2 to 2.1.3 as well but my problem is different: Notice: Undefined index: attribute_id in magento2/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Setup/UpgradeData.php on line 375 any ideas?

Comment: please check thsi que's ans http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/151108/update-magento-2-1-2-for-2-1-3-undefined-index-issue/151124#151124 @Semaj Nekeerv

Answer (score 11):

Updating/Upgrading to Magento 2.1.3 (via `composer`)

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.1.3 --no-update
composer update
rm -rf var/di var/generation
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

After upgrade, check your Magento version with the following command:

```
php bin/magento --version
```

Complete Working, I have just upgrade now.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you use Magento Vault then you also need to change module version in composer manualy to 100.2.*, read more: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.1.3CE.html#breaking-changes

An extra `magento setup:static-content:deploy` after installation is also worth to perform at the end of update process

Answer (score 1):

Connect your Magento 2 store using SSH and the go to its root directory.

First, run this command:

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.1.3 --no-update
```

Now update the composer

```
composer update
```

Now run the following command:

```
rm -rf var/di/* var/generation/* var/cache/* var/log/* var/page_cache/*
```

Now clean the cache:

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Now flush the cache:

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Now upgrade the setup:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Now compile the setup

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Lastly, reindex the indexer:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```