# Update Magento 2.1.2 for 2.1.3 : Undefined index issue

Tags: magento2, upgrade, magento-2.1.3

My magento current version is 2.1.2 and upgraded with Composer by following command:

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.1.3 --no-update
composer update
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

I'm getting following error while run command `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

> [Exception]
>     Notice: Undefined index: attribute_id in vendor\magento\module-catalog\Setup\UpgradeData.
>     php on line 375

Please help me for solve this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error comes from this method:

```
/**
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Setup\CategorySetup $categorySetup
 * @return void
 */
private function changePriceAttributeDefaultScope($categorySetup)
{
    $entityTypeId = $categorySetup->getEntityTypeId(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY);
    foreach (['price', 'cost', 'special_price'] as $attributeCode) {
        $attribute = $categorySetup->getAttribute($entityTypeId, $attributeCode);
        $categorySetup->updateAttribute(
            $entityTypeId,
/*375*/     $attribute['attribute_id'],
            'is_global',
            \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL
        );

    }
}
```

The feasible issue is the absence of the attribute from the list `['price', 'cost', 'special_price']` in your system. Maybe you’ve deleted one of them?

You can find all of them in the table `eav_attribute` usin the query:

```
SELECT * FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE `attribute_code` IN ('price', 'cost', 'special_price')
```

You should see something similar to this:

[image: query result]

If you want to restore your **cost** attribute use this query:

```
INSERT INTO eav_attribute (entity_type_id, attribute_code, attribute_model, backend_model, backend_type, backend_table, frontend_model, frontend_input, frontend_label, frontend_class, source_model, is_required, is_user_defined, default_value, is_unique, note) VALUES (4, 'cost', null, 'Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\Product\\Attribute\\Backend\\Price', 'decimal', null, null, 'price', 'Cost', null, null, 0, 1, null, 0, null);
```

Comment: hey,thank you so much actually at my side "cost" attribute not exist so getting this error.I solved this error by adding if condition above $categorySetup->updateAttribute.

Comment: @SnehaPanchal I was glad to help you. I recommend you to restore a system attribute to prevent other errors later.

Comment: But how can i restore?

Comment: @SnehaPanchal I added the query to my answer, please try it.

Comment: You need to make one more insert statement. See this answer - https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7804#issuecomment-268457430